# Most Efficient construction of pandas.DateTimeIndex from list of yyyyMMdd int

Tags: python, pandas

`pandas.DateTimeIndex` supports many input formats; however, most rely heavily on parsing strings containing the date/datetime information which can be inefficient with large data sets.  If the starting point for constructing a `DateTimeIndex` is a list of `int` in the format yyyyMMdd, what is the most efficient way to construct the `DateTimeIndex`?  The below conversion works; however, it is quite inefficient as it relies on date parsing from string.

```
import pandas
dates = [20180401, 20180402, 20180403]
dti = pandas.DatetimeIndex(map(str, dates)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format`:

```
dti = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y%m%d')
print (dti)

DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-01', '2018-04-02', '2018-04-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If input data is `csv` use parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Date
20180401
20180402
20180403"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0])

print (df)
        Date
0 2018-04-01
1 2018-04-02
2 2018-04-03

print (df.dtypes)
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: UV for the csv suggestion.. this really is the best option if possible.

Comment: @jpp - Thank you.